# How to know the save option "embed only the character used in the presentation" is turned on?

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I have MS PowerPoint file. I want to know if whether the save option "embed only the character used in the presentation is turned on. I am looking for in the internet, but I don't find the solution for my problem.
Anyone can help me to find solution to this problem? I am looking forward to hearing from you. Sorry if my English is not good.
(I am using C# and VBA)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can examine the XML that makes up the saved file, look at the PRESENTATION.XML file where you'll find something like this at the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:presentation xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"
                xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
                xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"
                embedTrueTypeFonts="1"
                saveSubsetFonts="1">
```

My copy of PPT here (Office 365) seems to be acting up; whether I save with the entire font embedded or with just needed characters (6 of them or so), the saved file is the same size and both values above are = "1".

Story of my life ... can't test any little thing w/o getting sidetracked by two or three apparent bugs.  ;-)